# Getting a React app adsense approved by rendering multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, adsense

Is there a way to pre-render and serve my React app and all of the 'pages' currently being served using react-router so it can be crawled by Google adsense and other search engine related bots?

I understand I can implement server side rendering, but it will only serve the content of the first 'page', and not the /blog, etc.

What I have is a site which provides people with a way to win money (by playing a simple guessing game) while I take a cut from the advertising which is served. The users are coming, but the ads are non-existent.

Any comments or feedback will be greatly appreciated as I am starting to think I will have to recreate this in a more static framework :(

Comment: *understand I can implement server side rendering, but it will only serve the content of the first 'page', and not the /blog, etc.* - it will serve the contents of all pages it requests. If it's SPA, only one page will be requested from server side. If you need to generate more page views, SPA is unsuitable. React can work on server side too. This sort of questions is suitable for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ , not for SO.

Comment: what tech stack would you recommend for such a site? I wanted to stay away from wordpress.Thanks @estus, I will head over to webmasters.stackexchange and ask it there.

Comment: I cannot recommend anything particular because this depends on your needs and skills. If you can make that with React+Express, then you can choose them.